# Simultaneous Objectively Equivalent Edits - Don't count as Rejected in Editor stats

Tags: feature-request, edits, rejected-edits

Some meta posts talk about editing conflicts when 2 or more people edit a post and save at nearly the same time (no time to react to the warning). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855193/this-while-loop-is-breaking-before-intended-can-anyone-help-me) is an example, which occured earlier when I made an edit. You can clearly see in the history that the changes in both submitted edits are formatting only and none is arguably better the other.

In a few of these meta posts are mentionned the Editor stats. However, I haven't seen anyone suggest that edit Reviewers could have an option other than REJECT/ACCEPT, or maybe add an option when you REJECT an edit that would basically make it not count in the Editor's stats.

[Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261498/problem-with-editing-simultaneously) the answer is basically that we shouldn't care. But in all honesty, if there are stats to begin with, I'd prefer them to accurately represent my edits' quality. One could argue that this happens rarely, but I do not believe that it's a legitimate reason to ignore this problem.

Comment: You'll need to include links to the suggestions, which the post doesn't do at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I can provide [This](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14433226) if that's what you're talking about. I sadly don't know how to show the edit made by the other user, you might want to guide me a little bit or find it by yourself, sorry. In any case, my feature suggestion here shouldn't Require my example to be valid, does it ? Please let me know if I'm not requesting correctly, I'm new to this.